# Ruby on Rails - Submit Review Text and Photos in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal

this is my first ever question on here, I only started writing code properly around 4-5 months ago so please be kind.

I'm trying to build a simple review site using Ruby on Rails. I want my users to be able to use a review form (inside a Bootstrap modal) to submit reviews and upload multiple photos at the same time but can't seem to get it to submit to both DB tables with just one button (tables are Reviews and Photos).

Currently users can submit photos and reviews in isolation with two separate buttons on the form but not together with one button. The issue with this two button solution is that the modal closes when either button is clicked and the form is submitted. I've looked into AJAX for the photo upload part but am not sure if this would work?

[Screenshot of review form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWEjX.jpg)

**Leave Review Button which triggers Modal Pop-up**

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-normal leave-review-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<%= @area.id %>">
Leave Review
</button>

 <% if !user_signed_in? %>
  <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal_<%= @area.id %>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Please <%= link_to "login", new_user_session_path %> or <%= link_to "sign up", new_user_registration_path %> to leave a review</h4>
      </div>


  <% else %>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal_<%= @area.id %>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Your Review</h4>
        <h5> Leave your honest review below </h5>
        <%= render 'areas/photo_upload_form' %>
      </div>



      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for current_user.reviews.new, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div id="stars"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 3, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

            <%= f.hidden_field :area_id, value: @area.id %>
            <%= form_for @area, url: area_photos_path(@area), method: 'post', html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>


          <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.submit "Add Review", class: "btn btn-normal" %>
          </div>

        <% end %>
       <% end %>
       <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#stars').raty({
    path: '/assets',
    scoreName: 'review[star]',
    score: 1
  });
</script>
```

**_photo_upload_form partial**

```
<%= form_for @area, url: area_photos_path(@area), method: 'post', html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-file text-babu">
     <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Select Photos
     <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
  </span>

   <div class="text-center">
     <%= f.submit "Add Photos", class: "btn btn-form" %>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create

   @area = Area.where(
                    id: review_params[:area_id]
                   ).first

    if !@area.nil?

      @has_reviewed = Review.where(
                        area_id: @area.id,
                        user_id: review_params[:user_id]
                      ).first

      if @has_reviewed.nil?
          # Allow to review
        @review = current_user.reviews.create(review_params)
        redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referrer)
        flash[:success] = "Review created..."
        else
          # Already reviewed
          flash[:success] = "You already reviewed this Area"
      end

    else
      flash[:alert] = "No area found"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.destroy
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referrer, notice: "Review successfully deleted")
  end


  private
   def review_params
     params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :star, :area_id, :user_id, :photo)
   end
 end
```

**photos_controller.rb**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @area = Area.find(params[:area_id])


    if params[:images]
      params[:images].each do |img|
        @area.photos.create(image: img, user_id: current_user.id)
      end

      @photos = @area.photos
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer, notice: "Saved...")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting form_for inside form_for. This is not the way to do this.

Please check out the example in the guides.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: Good point Paul, I hadn't thought about it that way. I will try to make it work using the guide you have posted.